# Air - What are the ways to recieve data from the client?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, air

I am making an Air application and I want it to receive data input from the user, like the user fills in a text field, and send them to the developer's app.
I am not asking for code , I am just looking for ways to do this.
Thanks

Comment: Use [`URLRequest`s](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/URLRequest.html) to send data to your backend.

Comment: Ok Thank for the reply , I am sorry for saying this but can u please exlpain more , like do I send the text to my server and then download it by my dev app? – @Vesper

Answer (score 2):

Here is a usefull link to Adobe's Flex in a Week videotraining:

[Flex in a Week, Day3](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flex/videotraining.html#day3). See section "Sending remote data".

I suggest you should watch the whole series if you got spare time. It will help you learn more about flex.

**More Info.**

One way that this trainning uses is *HTTPService.*

Within the `<fx:Declarations>` block create a new `HTTPService` like so:

```
<fx:Declarations>
   <s:HTTPService id="sendToServerService"
    url=" YOUR_SERVER_URL_HERE "  
    method="POST"/>
<fx:Declarations>
```

Note:  With the HTTPService class, you can communicate with PHP pages, ColdFusion pages, JavaServer Pages (JSP), Java servlets, Ruby on Rails, and Microsoft Active Server Pages (ASP).

An example of your server url is `http://www.example.com/remoteData/addUserDatat.cfm` using ColdFusion.

Within the *Script* block create a function that gets the data from the input:

```
protected function onSendBtn(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var data:String = textInput1.text;
    vehicleService.send(data);
}
```

In your Application file create a button and a textInput control:

```
<s:Button id="sendBtn" label="Send" click="onSendBtn(event)"/>
<s:TextInput id="textInput1"/>
```

Comment: I am sorry but i am talking about flash anyways thanks for the answer and you ve given me the idea on how it works